# Installing Vapor Toolbox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, vapor

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and having trouble following the installation guide for [Vapor Toolbox](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/install-toolbox.html) . I used swiftenv as described in the guide, and installed the Ubuntu 15.10 version of Swift, but attempting to install the toolbox results in the following:

```
$ curl -sL toolbox.vapor.sh | bash
✅  Compatible
Downloading...
Compiling...
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /home/william/.swiftenv/versions/DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-09-06-a/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /home/william/workspace/.vapor-toolbox-0.10.2/vapor-toolbox/.build/release.yaml
Installing...
bash: line 24: .build/release/Executable: No such file or directory
Use vapor --help and vapor <command> --help to learn more.
```

Trying 'vapor' results in:

```
$ vapor
vapor: command not found
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 install now works using same commands. Possibly the script at toolbox.vapor.sh was changed overnight?

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved in the latest version of the toolbox.

Install with

```
brew install vapor/tap/toolbox
```

or

```
curl -sL toolbox.vapor.sh | bash
```